# How load data into s3 without installing Hadoop and setting dll libraries

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, parquet

How to load parquet data into s3 without installing Hadoop and without setting the dll libraries (for example, for Windows), without `HADOOP_HOME`?

What kind of dependencies need to use in java project?

Now I used

```
org.apache.hadoop-hadoop-common 3.2.1
org.apache.hadoop-hadoop-aws 3.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop would require access to the underlying filesystem for creating tmp files. For that the native libraries are mandatory, irrespective of the Operating system.

For Windows, You would need `winutils.exe` and `hadoop.dll` files. If these libraries are not present, Hadoop or an application built on top of Hadoop will fail.

In addition to those dependencies for accessing S3 filesystem, you need the `aws-java-sdk-bundle` JAR.